# Saving BeatifulSoup output to mongo and loading it back again

Tags: python, mongodb, beautifulsoup

I have a crawler, that obtains certain web pages for my app.
I want to separate concerns, the crawler should be 'dumb', just fetch the page, take the BeautifulSoup JSON, and save it into MongoDB.

Other workers should then read the MongoDB documents and extract the 
relevant information into a relational model.

The question is how to safely convert a BeautifulSoup object to JSON (MongoDB document) and back to it self, safely and without errors.

Edit:
**Illustration**

```
 import urllib2
 import json
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com')
 res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(res.read())
 content = soup.findAll(text=True)
 soup_json = json.dumps(content)
 soup_json
```

Outputs:

```
'["doctype html", "Google", "(function(){\\nwindow.google={kEI:\\"LGktU9bfHqHk4wT1poGoAg\\",getEI:function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute(\\"eid\\")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI},https:function(){return\\"https:\\"==window.location.protocol},kEXPI:\\"4006,17259,4000116,4007661,4007830,4008067,4008133,4008142,4009033,4009352,4009565,4009641,4010297,4010806,4010858,4010899,4011228,4011258,4011679,4011959,4012373,4012504,4012507,4013338,4013374,4013414,4013416,4013591,4013723,4013747,4013787,4013823,4013967,4013979,4014016,4014431,4014515,4014636,4014649,4014671,4014792,4014804,4014813,4014991,4015119,4015155,4015195,4015234,4015260,4015320,4015444,4015497,4015514,4015582,4015589,4015637,4015638,4015640,4015690,4015772,4015853,4015904,4015991,4015995,4016007,4016047,4016062,4016139,4016167,4016193,4016304,4016311,4016407,8300007,8300015,8300018,8500149,8500157,10200002,10200012,10200029,10200030,10200040,10200045,10200048,10200053,10200055,10200066,10200083,10200103,10200120,10200134,10200157\\",kCSI:{e:\\"4006,17259,4000116,4007661,4007830,4008067,4008133,4008142,4009033,4009352,4009565,4009641,4010297,4010806,4010858,4010899,4011228,4011258,4011679,4011959,4012373,4012504,4012507,4013338,4013374,4013414,4013416,4013591,4013723,4013747,4013787,4013823,4013967,4013979,4014016,4014431,4014515,4014636,4014649,4014671,4014792,4014804,4014813,4014991,4015119,4015155,4015195,4015234,4015260,4015320,4015444,4015497,4015514,4015582,4015589,4015637,4015638,4015640,4015690,4015772,4015853,4015904,4015991,4015995,4016007,4016047,4016062,4016139,4016167,4016193,4016304,4016311,4016407,8300007,8300015,8300018,8500149,8500157,10200002,10200012,10200029,10200030,10200040,10200045,10200048,10200053,10200055,10200066,10200083,10200103,10200120,10200134,10200157\\",ei:\\"LGktU9bfHqHk4wT1poGoAg\\"},authuser:0,ml:function(){},kHL:\\"iw\\",time:function(){return(new Date).getTime()},log:function(a,b,c,h,k){var d=\\nnew Image,f=google.lc,e=google.li,g=\\"\\";d.onerror=d.onload=d.onabort=function(){delete f[e]};f[e]=d;c||-1!=b.search(\\"&ei=\\")||(g=\\"&ei=\\"+google.getEI(h));c=c||\\"/\\"+(k||\\"gen_204\\")+\\"?atyp=i&ct=\\"+a+\\"&cad=\\"+b+g+\\"&zx=\\"+google.time();a=/^http:/i;a.test(c)&&google.https()?(google.ml(Error(\\"GLMM\\"),!1,{src:c}),delete f[e]):(d.src=c,google.li=e+1)},lc:[],li:0,y:{},x:function(a,b){google.y[a.id]=[a,b];return!1},load:function(a,b,c){google.x({id:a+l++},function(){google.load(a,b,c)})}};var l=0;})();\\n(function(){google.sn=\\"webhp\\";google.timers={};google.startTick=function(a,b){google.timers[a]={t:{start:google.time()},bfr:!!b}};google.tick=function(a,b,g){google.timers[a]||google.startTick(a);google.timers[a].t[b]=g||google.time()};google.startTick(\\"load\\",!0);\\ntry{}catch(d){}})();\\nvar _gjwl=location;function _gjuc(){var a=_gjwl.href.indexOf(\\"#\\");if(0<=a&&(a=_gjwl.href.substring(a),0<a.indexOf(\\"&q=\\")||0<=a.indexOf(\\"#q=\\"))&&(a=a.substring(1),-1==a.indexOf(\\"#\\"))){for(var d=0;d<a.length;){var b=d;\\"&\\"==a.charAt(b)&&++b;var c=a.indexOf(\\"&\\",b);-1==c&&(c=a.length);b=a.substring(b,c);if(0==b.indexOf(\\"fp=\\"))a=a.substring(0,d)+a.substring(c,a.length),c=d;else if(\\"cad=h\\"==b)return 0;d=c}_gjwl.href=\\"/search?\\"+a+\\"&cad=h\\";return 1}return 0}\\nfunction _gjh(){!_gjuc()&&window.google&&google.x&&google.x({id:\\"GJH\\"},function(){google.nav&&google.nav.gjh&&google.nav.gjh()})};\\nwindow._gjh&&_gjh();", "#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:left}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-left:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:right}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}", "body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#36c}.q{color:#00c}.ts td{padding:0}.ts{border-collapse:collapse}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-right:4px}input{font-family:inherit}a.gb1,a.gb2,a.gb3,a.gb4{color:#11c !important}body{background:#fff;color:black}a{color:#11c;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#36c}a:visited{color:#551a8b}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline}a.gb3:hover{text-decoration:none}#ghead a.gb2:hover{color:#fff !important}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-right:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#eee;border:solid 1px;border-color:#ccc #ccc #999 #999;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}.ftl,#fll a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/srpr/nav_logo80.png) 0 -258px repeat-x;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#ccc}.lst:focus{outline:none}#addlang a{padding:0 3px}.tiah{width:458px}", "(function(){var src=\'/images/nav_logo176.png\';var iesg=false;document.body.onload = function(){window.n && window.n();if (document.images){new Image().src=src;}\\nif (!iesg){document.f&&document.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();}\\n}\\n})();", " ", "\\u00e7\\u00e9\\u00f4\\u00e5\\u00f9", " ", "\\u00fa\\u00ee\\u00e5\\u00f0\\u00e5\\u00fa", " ", "\\u00ee\\u00f4\\u00e5\\u00fa", " ", "YouTube", " ", "\\u00e7\\u00e3\\u00f9\\u00e5\\u00fa", " ", "Gmail", " ", "Drive", " ", "\\u00e9\\u00e5\\u00ee\\u00ef", " ", "\\u00f2\\u00e5\\u00e3", " \\u00bb", "\\u00e4\\u00e9\\u00f1\\u00e8\\u00e5\\u00f8\\u00e9\\u00e9\\u00fa \\u00e0\\u00fa\\u00f8\\u00e9\\u00ed", " | ", "\\u00e4\\u00e2\\u00e3\\u00f8\\u00e5\\u00fa", " | ", "\\u00e4\\u00e9\\u00eb\\u00f0\\u00f1", " ", "\\u00e9\\u00f9\\u00f8\\u00e0\\u00ec", "\\u00a0", "\\u00e7\\u00e9\\u00f4\\u00e5\\u00f9 \\u00ee\\u00fa\\u00f7\\u00e3\\u00ed", "\\u00eb\\u00ec\\u00e9 \\u00f9\\u00f4\\u00e4", "Google.co.il \\u00e2\\u00ed \\u00e1: ", "\\u0627\\u0644\\u0639\\u0631\\u0628\\u064a\\u0629", " ", "English", " \\u00f4\\u00f8\\u00f1\\u00e5\\u00ed \\u00e1-Google", "\\u00f4\\u00fa\\u00f8\\u00e5\\u00f0\\u00e5\\u00fa \\u00f2\\u00f1\\u00f7\\u00e9\\u00e9\\u00ed", "\\u00e4\\u00eb\\u00ec \\u00e0\\u00e5\\u00e3\\u00e5\\u00fa Google", "Google.com", "\\u00a9 2013 - ", "\\u00f4\\u00f8\\u00e8\\u00e9\\u00e5\\u00fa \\u00e5\\u00fa\\u00f0\\u00e0\\u00e9\\u00ed", "if(google.y)google.y.first=[];(function(){function b(a){window.setTimeout(function(){var c=document.createElement(\\"script\\");c.src=a;document.getElementById(\\"xjsd\\").appendChild(c)},0)}google.dljp=function(a){google.xjsu=a;b(a)};google.dlj=b;})();\\nif(!google.xjs){window._=window._||{};window._._DumpException=function(e){throw e};if(google.timers&&google.timers.load.t){google.timers.load.t.xjsls=new Date().getTime();}google.dljp(\'/xjs/_/js/k\\\\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.X67G-1Nbjpc.O/m\\\\x3dsb_he,pcc/rt\\\\x3dj/d\\\\x3d1/sv\\\\x3d1/rs\\\\x3dAItRSTO_vkVhEK6twEUdYclvmSrFcRL-Zw\');google.xjs=1;}google.pmc={\\"sb_he\\":{\\"agen\\":true,\\"cgen\\":true,\\"client\\":\\"heirloom-hp\\",\\"dh\\":true,\\"ds\\":\\"\\",\\"eqch\\":true,\\"fl\\":true,\\"host\\":\\"google.co.il\\",\\"jsonp\\":true,\\"msgs\\":{\\"dym\\":\\"\\u00e4\\u00e0\\u00ed \\u00e4\\u00fa\\u00eb\\u00e5\\u00e5\\u00f0\\u00fa \\u00ec:\\",\\"lcky\\":\\"\\u00e9\\u00e5\\u00fa\\u00f8 \\u00ee\\u00e6\\u00ec \\u00ee\\u00f9\\u00eb\\u00ec\\",\\"lml\\":\\"\\u00ec\\u00ee\\u00e9\\u00e3\\u00f2 \\u00f0\\u00e5\\u00f1\\u00f3\\",\\"oskt\\":\\"\\u00eb\\u00ec\\u00e9 \\u00e4\\u00e6\\u00f0\\u00e4\\",\\"psrc\\":\\"\\u00e7\\u00e9\\u00f4\\u00e5\\u00f9 \\u00e6\\u00e4 \\u00e4\\u00e5\\u00f1\\u00f8 \\u00ee\\\\u003Ca href=\\\\\\"/history\\\\\\"\\\\u003E\\u00e4\\u00e9\\u00f1\\u00e8\\u00e5\\u00f8\\u00e9\\u00e9\\u00fa \\u00e4\\u00e0\\u00e9\\u00f0\\u00e8\\u00f8\\u00f0\\u00e8\\\\u003C/a\\\\u003E \\u00f9\\u00ec\\u00ea\\",\\"psrl\\":\\"\\u00e4\\u00f1\\u00f8\\",\\"sbit\\":\\"\\u00e7\\u00f4\\u00f9 \\u00ec\\u00f4\\u00e9 \\u00fa\\u00ee\\u00e5\\u00f0\\u00e4\\",\\"srch\\":\\"\\u00e7\\u00e9\\u00f4\\u00e5\\u00f9 \\u00e1-Google\\"},\\"ovr\\":{},\\"pq\\":\\"\\",\\"qcpw\\":false,\\"scd\\":10,\\"sce\\":5,\\"stok\\":\\"AVgtYJUWkObPx6V5QqvD7hitdNE\\"},\\"pcc\\":{}};google.y.first.push(function(){if(google.med){google.med(\'init\');google.initHistory();google.med(\'history\');}});if(google.j&&google.j.en&&google.j.xi){window.setTimeout(google.j.xi,0);}", "(function(){if(google.timers&&google.timers.load.t){var b,c,d,e,g=function(a,f){a.removeEventListener?(a.removeEventListener(\\"load\\",f,!1),a.removeEventListener(\\"error\\",f,!1)):(a.detachEvent(\\"onload\\",f),a.detachEvent(\\"onerror\\",f))},h=function(a){e=(new Date).getTime();++c;a=a||window.event;a=a.target||a.srcElement;g(a,h)},k=document.getElementsByTagName(\\"img\\");b=k.length;for(var l=c=0,m;l<b;++l)m=k[l],m.complete||\\"string\\"!=typeof m.src||!m.src?++c:m.addEventListener?(m.addEventListener(\\"load\\",h,!1),m.addEventListener(\\"error\\",\\nh,!1)):(m.attachEvent(\\"onload\\",h),m.attachEvent(\\"onerror\\",h));d=b-c;var n=function(){if(google.timers.load.t){google.timers.load.t.ol=(new Date).getTime();google.timers.load.t.iml=e;google.kCSI.imc=c;google.kCSI.imn=b;google.kCSI.imp=d;void 0!==google.stt&&(google.kCSI.stt=google.stt);google.csiReport&&google.csiReport()}};window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener(\\"load\\",n,!1):window.attachEvent&&\\nwindow.attachEvent(\\"onload\\",n);google.timers.load.t.prt=e=(new Date).getTime()};})();\\n"]'
```

This JSON should be saved in MongoDB, in a manner that will allow me to respote a Beatiful soup object from it later.

Comment: Can you possibly submit an example of what you are doing and what your input and output expectations are in your question? That would make things a lot clearer for everyone if you did.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Busy. But I meant, please show us JSON of `content_dict` **and** what you **expect** to get back when **reading** from MongoDB. Maybe not **all** but a *sample*.

Comment: Well, it sounds a bit unlogical: if you want to save the page for further processing, you don't need BeautifulSoup at all. Also, why mongodb..sounds like you are going to store html in json document database..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, you really don't have to build the soup before storing it into mongo (or any database).

Here are my reasons:

(1) After you turned it into a soup, which is a class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup', when you store it into mongo, it will be in a format of txt, either in json format or whatever. Next time you try to pull from the database, you need to call the BeautifulSoup function again to rebuild the soup from string/json, which clearly you BeautifulSoup-ed twice.

(2) Soup is basically a xml tree built based on the HTML page. BeautifulSoup will parse the tree and sometimes fix broken/missing tags and do some "smart staff" that you might not actually want, or modify the HTML page slightly. For example, you can get different types of results based on the parser you are using, "lxml"/"html5"... So using beautifulsoup before storing data might screw you up.

In conclusion: I would recommend you store the raw HTML content without doing any work. And the simplest way to store them is just building document following the format of:

```
{"url":"www.xxx.com/..", "html":"<DOCTYPE!>...."}
```

In this case, you basically mirrored/indexed the website to your local machine and won't miss any information.

Here are some codes that help you store/retrieve html using mongo:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
>>> db = client.oleg
>>> 
>>> # get the raw html 
... url = "http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#"
>>> import urllib2
>>> html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
>>> html[:100]
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"\n  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xh'
>>> 
>>>
>>> # store the <key:value> -> <url:html> into mongo for later use
... db.tikhonov.insert({"url":url, "html":html})
ObjectId('532e6904866cd3431a90c618')
>>>
>>> # retrieve the stored html by search the url
... record = db.tikhonov.find_one({"url":url})
>>> record['url']
u'http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#'
>>> 
>>> # turn html txt into soup and start parsing
... from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(record['html'])
>>> soup.find("h1").text
u'Beautiful Soup Documentation\xb6'
```

PS:
It is a WONDERFUL idea to separate the "extracting html" step from the "parsing" step. You can start collecting the HTML page without any parsing because it is always the HTTP request takes the most time. And you can start collecting raw html page and meanwhile writing&testing your parser.

***DEFINITELY CHECK OUT THE TERMS OF SERVICES BEFORE SCRAPING OR STORING INTELLECTUAL PROPERTIES LOCALLY.***

Comment: Thanks, I gave this issue some thought over the weekend and I think that you are right :)

One thing though, is the efficiency of storing such information in MongoDB, isn't it better to use good old fashioned files?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @OlegTikhonov It really depends. If you are doing a small scale scraping (<1million http request). It really doesn't matter you store it. But I would prefer using database since it is more organized and accept multi thread writing and reading. If you are doing a large scale scraping, check out Nutch2.0